# psycopg2 library not loaded

Tags: python, psycopg2

I installed psycopg2 using pip but when I import psycopg2 I get this error

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/lce21/Documents/GitHub/hazen-web- 
app/hazen-web-app/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library 
not loaded: /usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib

  Referenced from: /Users/lce21/Documents/GitHub/hazen-web- 
app/hazen-web-app/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so

  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib' 
(no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), 
'/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), 
'/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.6/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such 
file), '/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), 
'/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file)
```

Things tried:
pip install psycopg2-binary

MacOS pip install psycopg2 with sudo and in the venv. No errors when I installed.  Postgres installed.

I might need to change location of files but I don't know how to do that

Comment: More information needed 1) OS and version? 2) Where did you do the `pip install psycopg2` in a virtualenv or in the system? 3) Where there any errors when you did the initial install?  4) Do you have Postgres installed on the machine?

Comment: MacOS pip install psycopg2 with sudo and in the venv. No errors when I installed.  Postgres installed.

Comment: At this point uninstall both `psycopg2` and `psycopg2-binary`. I have seen issues before when both where installed. Then try installing `psycopg2-binary` and report back.

Comment: already tried this before. Same error remains

Comment: Did you uninstall from both the system and the venv? How was Postgres installed?

Comment: I used sudo, does that mean I uninstalled also from the venv right? For Postgres: brew install postgresql

Comment: 1) You don't need to use sudo to install into a venv, assuming it is in your home directory. 2) Activate the venv and do `pip freeze` to see what is installed. If `pyscopg2` and /or `psycopg2-binary` are installed then just do `pip uninstall <program>`. 3) Deactivate the venv and then repeat `pip freeze` to see what is installed in system. There you will need to `sudo pip uninstall <program>`.

Comment: tried this, but got the same error

Comment: unsistalled from both, pip freeze both in the venv and without venv showed psycopg2 or psycopg2-binary weren't installed. Then I activated the venv and installed it again.

Comment: postgres was installed with brew install postgres

Comment: @AdrianKlaver's directions worked for me. saw i had different `pyscopg2` versions. uninstalled it from venv, deactivated venv, uninstalled it from system, reactivated venv, reinstalled on venv. no more import error!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was that I had installed in my system a different version of postgresql than the version on my virtual env.

So I had to unistall from the system postgresql and then reinstall it.